# Can I determine the previous duplicate of a reopened question?

Tags: discussion, support

When I returned from a break, a question that I had been looking at had been hammered by a gold badger and subsequently reopened by another. I was curious what the duplicate had been, but I couldn't see a way to find out. I looked at the question timeline, and although there is an entry where it was closed as duplicate, there's nothing there that indicates what the duplicate was. Is there any other way to determine this?

I can link to the specific question if it would be helpful, but I'm mostly just wondering if it would be possible in general.

Comment: Don't panic, its all still there ;)

Comment: Haha, yeah it sure is. Somehow I didn't know about /revisions.

Comment: That's why I was asking for it. Also I couldn't remember the syntax. Upvoted to dense the FAQ networking.

Comment: As many times as I've clicked the link to go to it, I guess I never really paid attention to the url. Thanks!

Comment: It's _the mice_ that keep this site going :)